# How to efficiently search for viewWithTag in navigationItems (rightBarButtonItems & leftBarButtonItems)

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there a way to efficiently search for UIView viewWithTag in navigationItems (rightBarButtonItems & leftBarButtonItems).

I would have aexpected the view to be found the regular way:

```
UIView* myView = [screen.view viewWithTag:tag];
```

But that didn't work. What worked is:

```
        UIView* myView = [screen.view viewWithTag:tag];

        if (!myView) {
            for (UIView* barButtonItem in screen.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems) {
                if (barButtonItem.tag == tag)
                {
                    myView = [barButtonItem valueForKey:@"view"];
                    myView.tag = barButtonItem.tag;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!myView) {
            for (UIView* barButtonItem in screen.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems) {
                if (barButtonItem.tag == tag)
                {
                    myView = [barButtonItem valueForKey:@"view"];
                    myView.tag = barButtonItem.tag;
                }
            }
        }
```

But that is very ugly code. Is there anything nicer that could be done?

Comment: Just curious about barButtonItem being a UIView,UIBarButtonItem is a NSObject class.

Comment: barButtonItem is not a subclass of UIView. But I make it a view by: myView = [barButtonItem valueForKey:@"view"]; It works. I checked it

Answer (score 1):

You actually can get the view with this.

```
UIView *view = [self.navigationController.navigationBar viewWithTag:4];
```

UIBarButtonItem created from custom view, set the custom view's tag to 4.

UIBarButtonItem created from system Item, set the tag after it being set to rightBarButtonItems.

```
UIBarButtonItem *editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit
                                            target:self action:@selector(viewWithTag:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems =
    [NSArray arrayWithObjects:editButton, nil];
UIView *view = [editButton valueForKey:@"view"];
view.tag = 4;
```